# WMI, Win32_Process

Tags: c#, wmi

I want to find which processes are using a particular dll using **C# and WMI**. Tried 3 approaches...

1. Getting CIM_DataFile object for the file and then get related processes.. It works for system dlls but not for My application dll.. It wont show any process associated with that even though process explorer shows the same.
2. Enumerating through all the processes and then enumerating through the process modules to find the DLL is being used or not.. Here also same issue.. working for system dlls but not for my application dlls.
3. Getting CIM_ProcessExecutables objects and getting DLLS/EXE and its linked processes... here also same thing is happening...

Is there anything im missing?

enter code here

```
using System;
using System.Management;
// Search the processes which have a certain file open
class App
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        WhoHasThisFileOpen("c:\\\\users\\\\pawarnit\\\\source\\\\repos\\\\myprogram\\\\myprogram\\\\bin\\\\debug\\\\differentDllFile.dll");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static void WhoHasThisFileOpen(string objectQry)
    {
        SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("select name from cim_datafile where name = '" + objectQry +"'" );
    using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new
    ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File Name: {0} \nIs currently opened by:",
                mo.Properties["Name"].Value);
                // Get processes having this File open
                foreach (ManagementBaseObject b in mo.GetRelated("Win32_Process"))
                {
                    ShowProcessProperties(b.ToString());
                    b.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    static void ShowProcessProperties(string objectClass)
    {
        using (ManagementObject process = new ManagementObject(objectClass))
        {
            process.Get();
            PropertyDataCollection processProperties = process.Properties;
            Console.WriteLine("ProcessID: {0,6} \tCommandLine: {1}",
            processProperties["ProcessID"].Value,
            processProperties["CommandLine"].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Added for 1st case.. Hope this is clear

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.modules(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Have you tried using [ProcessModules](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processmodule?view=netframework-4.7.1)? (I have to give credit to @HansPassant for the initial comment but the linked page wasn't the greatest. I linked the .Net Api Browser page instead.

Comment: It wont help here.. need to know why above thing is not working..